# plot triangle in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, convolution

I want to plot a triangle based on an equation in Matlab.

I create equation `g` for my triangle which I need to use for convolution later.

The picture below is the simple triangle I want to plot

[image]

However my code produces this:

[image]

My question is, how to make the other side slope? and after the top of my triangle will not return to `1`. In case I want to make it triangle

Here is my code:

```
%%Declaration
dt = 0.001 ;

%Equation for h(t) as rect function
T = -1: dt: 3;
g = 0.*(T>= -1 & T< -0) + (-2*T).*(T>= 0 & T<=1) + 0.*(T> 1& T<=3) ;

%Triangle at Graph(g) is at negative side, so need to turn at positive side 
h= abs(g);

%Plot Graph(G) in declaration of Graph(h) in absoulute value

plot(T,h);ylim([0 2.5]);ylabel('Triangular,h');xlabel('Time (Second)'); title('Figure 2(a)')
```

Comment: Maybe try `T = [-1:dt:3, -1]`?

Comment: still got the same answer. What doe -1 means at the back?

Comment: Sorry nevermind, I thought you were trying to plot an actual triangle, not a line with a triangular hump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your equation for `h`, you have three sections. You also have three sections in your chart. The first and last section are `0` and the second section is an increasing line.

```
h = 0.*(T>= -1 & T< 0) + (2*T).*(T>= 0 & T<=1) + 0.*(T> 1& T<=3);
```

So section 1 is between -1 and 0 and equals 0 i.e. `0.*(T>= -1 & T< 0)`, section two is between 0 and 1 and is a positive increasing line with gradient 2 crossing the y-axis at 0 i.e. has the y=mx+c equation of y=2x and in your case y is `h` and x is `T` thus `(2*T).*(T>= 0 & T<=1)`.

So now all you need is the downward sloping equivalent. It slopes down from (1,2) to (2,0) which give the equation y = -2x + 4 so finally we get

```
h = 0.*(T>= -1 & T< 0) + (2*T).*(T>= 0 & T<=1) + (-2*T + 4).*(T> 1 & T<=2)  + 0.*(T> 2 & T<=3);
```

Comment: Ohh like that.. Sorry i forgot the basic. I should know the gradient first, right. :) Then I can forward to play with coding. 
Thanks. .